# How to constrain content width

Tags: html, css

I know I could simply use a container `div` in this situation, but wanted to know if it is possible without it.

I want my layout to be fluid between 640px-1280px but stay fixed beyond that. I have a div which spans `100%` of the width because it is coloured and I want that colour to span the width of the browser even if it is enlarged beyond the 1280px upper bound but I want the content to be in the middle of the page with the maximum content width being 1280px.

I hope that makes sense.

I DO NOT want to use a repeated background image incase the user increases the font size which would change where all the objects are located.

Comment: You could use css @media-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try css max-width or post some code or example url

[w3schools max-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp)

Comment: `max-width` wouldn't work here. I tried doing an example to post but its really hard as I can do the WRONG thing. Hopefully this will explain what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/vBsfm/1/ ...only I want it with one div, not two.

Comment: then apply the colour to the body instead of another div. See [link]http://jsfiddle.net/vBsfm/2/

Comment: That's NOT what I am after. The colour doesn't apply to the whole background, just the height of the `div#main`.

Comment: Then I see no alternative but to have the other DIV. You want full width colour the same hight of the main div with the main div having a fluid size between a min & max width without using a b-ground image. If you don't place a block element of some form it's not possible as you have nothing to apply your style to. Why are you opposed to the 2nd div?

Comment: Thinking on, the only other way is the main div left & right boarder being coloured and oversized to fit your spec but again I don't think this will work for you as you want 100% width. If you can do without 100% width that maybe an alternative?

Comment: I'm not against the second `div` if its the only way, was just wondering if there was a way to avoid it. Thanks for the suggestions, I don't think the border trick (although very clever!) will work how I want so I will just use another `div`. Thanks again!